# Error of react-native-os and gradle versions in react-native project

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, version, deprecated

So I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@walletconnect/react-native-dapp library. The steps is clear I installed `npx rn-nodeify --install --hack` to have all important libraries for supporting wallet connect. And here is my `"postinstall": "./node_modules/.bin/rn-nodeify --install 'crypto,buffer,react-native-randombytes,stream,os' --hack, patch-package"`. And of course os added `react-native-os` lib on my package.json too.

Project works perfectly on IOS but I got error running on android. Here is the error

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/name/Workspace/projectName/node_modules/react-native-os/android/build.gradle' line: 47
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-os'.

> Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.facebook.react:react-native:+] on object of type org.gradle.ap

and here is the node_modules/react-native-os/android/build.gradle' line: 47 which I got error

46: `dependencies {`
47:    `compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'`
48: `}`

So I did a well research and find out that compile function has been deprecated since Gradle 4.10 (Aug 27, 2018), and were finally removed in Gradle 7.0 (Apr 9, 2021).

The aforementioned configurations should be replaced by implementation.

My project's gradle version is 7.2.1. And definitely I can't always go to react-native-os/android/build.gradle file and change the `compile` word to `implementation`!! And I can't downgrade my project's gradle version.

I tried to use patch-package lib which let me to modify files in node modules. But after that I see more deprecated stuff and errors. So what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Having same issue with react-native-os + gradle >= 7 in an expo managed project. Best solution for me was to install 'patch-package', waiting for a new release of react-native-os (the github repo main branch already has the fix).
See [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) docs for usage and don't forget to add a 'postinstall' script to your package.json to apply all patches.